# How to call function from Nodejs running as windows service

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-services, node-windows

I have created windows service from nodeJs application using node-windows package. Below is my code.

Main.js

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name:'SNMPCollector',
  description: 'SNMP collector',
  script: './app.js',
  nodeOptions: [
    '--harmony',
    '--max_old_space_size=4096'
  ]
  //, workingDirectory: '...'
});

// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
// process is available as a service.
svc.on('install',function(){
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();

/* svc.uninstall(); */
```

App.js

```
const { workerData, parentPort, isMainThread, Worker } = require('worker_threads')


var NodesList = ["xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx"]

module.exports.run = function (Nodes) {
  if (isMainThread) {
    while (Nodes.length > 0) {

    // my logic

      })
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I run main.js, it creates a windows service and I can see the service running in services.msc

But, how can I call this run() method which is inside the running service, from any outside application? I couldn't find any solution for this, any help would be great.

Comment: You can create a CLI for it. Does it not work?

Comment: how to crate cli ?

Comment: I can't explain the whole thing here in the comment. But I highly recommend this article https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/18/command-line-app-with-nodejs

Comment: You don't create a service to *run* it on demand using other scripts/programs; a service is there to perform some kind of tasks or operations. You can create an HTTP endpoint using that service that you may use.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider simply importing your `run` function where you need it and run it there, then there is no need for a windows service or `main.js` - this assumes that "any outside application" is a Node application.

In your other application you you do the folowing:

```
const app = require('<path to App.js>');
app.run(someNodes)
```

For broader usage or if you do need to run it as a service, you could be starting an express (or another webserver) in your App.js with an endpoint that invokes your `run` function. Then from anywhere else you'll need to make an http call to that endpoint.

App.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { workerData, parentPort, isMainThread, Worker } = require('worker_threads')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

var NodesList = ["xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx"]

const run = function (Nodes) {
  if (isMainThread) {
    while (Nodes.length > 0) {

    // my logic

      })
    }
  }
}

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => res.send(run(req.body)))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

(Based off of example for express - https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

You'll need to install both express and body-parser: `$ npm install --save express body-parser` from the directory of App.js.

From your other applications you will need to call the endpoint `http://localhost:3000` with a POST request and the `Nodes` as a JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose it on a port like the other answer mentions, though you'll want to make sure you don't expose it more broadly depending on the environment you're running in. There's a good answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/247176/iptables-only-allow-localhost-access) on ensuring the port is locked down.

As an alternative to exposing it on a port you can simply call the function by running the command in any other application:

```
node -e 'require("/somePathToYourJS/app").run()'
```

One concern is that app.js will now run at whatever permissions the calling application has. Although that can be resolved by running `runas` prior. More details [here](https://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-runas-command-prompt/). But an example is:

```
runas /user:domainname\username "node -e 'require(^"/somePathToYourJS/app^").run()'"
```